# Will loop reference stop garbage collection?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

In my class which inherited `TreeViewItem`  I used a field to store the parent `TreeView` object

```
TreeView _parentTreeView
```

Since `TreeView` will definitely have a reference to the `TreeViewItem` while the `TreeViewItem` holds a reference to the parent. Will this prevent both `TreeView` and `TreeViewItem` from being garbage collected?

Comment: If the root reference to treview is not accessible anywhere, It may be collected..

Comment: C#/.Net does not use reference counting for garbage collection. It uses graph theory to know when items are no longer "rooted" to determine that they are no longer reachable by the program.